# Where does "php artisan serve" read configurations in Mac OS?

Tags: php, laravel, macos

I'm running my laravel project using `php artisan serve`, however I got stuck because I need to upload some heavy file to the server.

I've been reading on where `php.ini` file is in Mac, and i realized that mac has a default php configuration and if won't be read from `php.ini` at least you copy the `php.default.ini` from `/etc` and make a file in `/etc` called `php.ini`.

I already struggled with this on Linux, it turns out that since I'm running `php artisan serve`, the configuration was being taken from `/etc/php/cli` (Honestly i don't remember well the exact path, but the point is that it wasn't being taken from the `php.ini` standard file) but in Mac this folder doesn't exists, and even if I make a copy of `php.default.ini` and save it in `/etc`, my project seems to be ignoring that configuration. (which makes sense because it must be reading it from another path, just like in linux).

Does anyone know something about it? Has someone struggled with this before?

Comment: Terminal > `php --ini`

Answer (score 0):

Write a `<?php phpinfo();?>` in anywhere and its output will show you the path of the loaded php.ini file.

Comment: If you're using Artisan, you need to do `php -i` in the Terminal. The webserver may be using a *different* php.ini (or even a different version of PHP entirely).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest getting the `php.ini` location by using `phpinfo()` and then running this on your terminal to check if there are other ini directives used:

```
# assuming your php.ini is located on `/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini` according to `phpinfo()`:

grep -rEn post_max_size etc/php/7.2/cli
```